# Does anyone know about Chess with Scid?

Tags: games, chess

Hi I'm installing stockfish to be used on scid. I followed these two tutorials, using stockfish from the stockfish website rather than from git.

> https://www.chess.com/article/view/scid--stockfish
>   http://support.stockfishchess.org/kb/advanced-topics/compiling-stockfish-on-linux

I installed scid by:

```
sudo apt-get install scid
```

I downloaded engine binaries for stockfish7 for Linux from

> https://stockfishchess.org/download/

I read  that you need to compile it first so i compiled the stockfish engine with sudo apt-get install git g++. Tested it with make profile-build ARCH=x86-32 then I went to add the engine in scid, with settings:

```
name:stockfish
command: stockfish
directory: /home/user/Desktop/stockfish-7-linux/Linux/src/.stockfish
UCI on
```

but then It tells me that `unable to start the program: stockfish`.

that error is the default response for any error. If I typed in folders that don't exist and a file that doesn't exist, it gives that error too. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that stockfish is available prepackaged for Ubuntu. Just `sudo apt-get install stockfish`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need the absolute path to command , in my case:

```
/usr/local/bin/stockfish
```

Directory i just pressed button at the right that point to scid in your home directory :

```
~/.scid
```

Notice that if you have done steps on [stockfish page](http://support.stockfishchess.org/kb/advanced-topics/compiling-stockfish-on-linux) the final step is :

./stockfish

But to use it as i did do one more step :

```
sudo make install
```

This give the output directory .